# How to Change Application Theme in UWP and WinUi

Tags: c#, uwp, winui

I want to change my UWP (winui 2.5) App theme, I used the following code

```
private void OnThemeRadioButtonChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedTheme = ((RadioButton)sender)?.Tag?.ToString();
            ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;

            if (selectedTheme != null)
            {
                App.RootTheme = App.GetEnum<ElementTheme>(selectedTheme);
                if (selectedTheme == "Dark")
                {
                    titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
                }
                else if (selectedTheme == "Light")
                {
                    titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.Black;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark)
                    {
                        titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.Black;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and in App.xaml.cs

```
public static ElementTheme RootTheme
        {
            get
            {
                if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement rootElement)
                {
                    return rootElement.RequestedTheme;
                }

                return ElementTheme.Default;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement rootElement)
                {
                    rootElement.RequestedTheme = value;
                }
            }
        }

public static TEnum GetEnum<TEnum>(string text) where TEnum : struct
        {
            if (!typeof(TEnum).GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Generic parameter 'TEnum' must be an enum.");
            }
            return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), text);
        }
```

But the result is not expected As you can see, the buttons have a problem with changing the theme I copied the code from Microsoft Xaml Controls Gallery sample project

[image]

and this is microsoft sample that work fine

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install [Microsoft Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/) and use exensions

```
toolkit:TitleBarExtensions.ButtonBackgroundColor="Transparent"
toolkit:TitleBarExtensions.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor="Transparent"
```